# LaTeX Find and Replace with variables between { }

Tags: labels

Using gb4e I have, say, two labels in:

```
\begin{exe}
\ex\label{mi1}
    \begin{xlist}
```

---

and

```
\begin{exe}
\ex\label{mi2}
    \begin{xlist}
```

---

Question: How do I get via FIND and REPLACE:

```
\begin{exe}\label{mi1}
\ex
    \begin{xlist}
```

---

and

```
\begin{exe\label{mi2}
\ex
    \begin{xlist}
```

---

In order to get this in just one Find and Replace instruction for a large text with many examples, which variable should I write between the braces in `\label{ }`? Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please place your code between the code tags (button `{}`)

Comment: your question appears to be about editing the source file, that is unrelated to latex, and just depends on which editor you are using, which you have not stated.

Comment: So, do  you want to move the label inside `exe`  just before `\ex`?